# Nested for loops optimization in Java - streams alternative leads to different result

Tags: java, multithreading, stream, thread-safety

I have tried to run in parallel 13 for loops in Java and I tried to rewrite them with DoubleStream. The problem is that the output provided by the same code, but with "for" loops is different than the one provided by the streams alternative.

Another problem is that the "for" loops implementation takes a lot of time and I need to improve it. I assume the streams approach is not right because the operation that I do is serial and the order of threads is random, so the processing is not done quite right.
Is there any way I can acquire the same result or parallelize the for loops?
My code is below:

```
        DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(a -> {
            System.out.println("Iteration " + a + " min var " + wrapperMinVariation.minVariation + "values: " + wrapperMinA.minA + " " + wrapperMinB.minB);
            DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(b -> {
                System.out.println("Iteration " + a +" "+ b +" min var " + wrapperMinVariation.minVariation + "values: " + wrapperMinA.minA + " " + wrapperMinB.minB);
                DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(c -> {
                    DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(d -> {
                        DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(e -> {
                            DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(f -> {
                                DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(g -> {
                                    DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(h -> {
                                        DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(m -> {
                                            DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(n -> {
                                                DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(o -> {
                                                    DoubleStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 0.2).limit(5).parallel().forEach(p -> {
                                                        double variation = 0;
                                                        for (int i = 0; i < wrapper.list.size(); i++) {
                                                            
                                                            // operations with a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,m,n,o,p

                                                            variation += variationPerMatch;
                                                        }
                                                        double finalVariationMatches = variation / wrapper.list.size();
                                                        if (finalVariationMatches < wrapperMinVariation.minVariation) {
                                                            wrapperMinA.minA = a;
                                                            wrapperMinB.minB = b;
                                                            wrapperMinC.minC = c;
                                                            wrapperMinD.minD = d;
                                                            wrapperMinE.minE = e;
                                                            wrapperMinF.minF = f;
                                                            wrapperMinG.minG = g;
                                                            wrapperMinH.minH = h;
                                                            wrapperMinM.minM = m;
                                                            wrapperMinN.minN = n;
                                                            wrapperMinO.minO = o;
                                                            wrapperMinP.minP = p;
                                                            wrapperMinVariation.minVariation = finalVariationMatches;
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: what is the mother of God are you trying to do? May be better if you can explain clearly what you actually what to achieve first? This blocks looks like ASCII art more then code

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the output provided by the same code, but with "for" loops is different than the one provided by the streams alternative.

Since the code in the question is incomplete, it is not possible to know why parallelizing it gives different answers.  One possibility is that it is a consequence of floating point rounding error.  If the computations happen in a different order, that could lead to answers being rounded differently.

> I assume the streams approach is not right because the operation that I do is serial and the order of threads is random, so the processing is not done quite right.

That is plausible; see above.

---

> Is there any way I can acquire the same result or parallelize the for loops?

Since we cannot understand what the code is supposed to do, I don't think we can suggest alternatives.  (The best answer might be a completely different algorithmic approach ... that doesn't involve 5<sup>12</sup> separate computations.)

However, I would note that adding `parallel()` at each level is likely to make the code slower rather than faster.  Running tasks in parallel introduces overheads.  If the tasks are too small (i.e. too fine grained) the overheads of creating and managing the tasks can swamp the savings that could potentially be achieved by parallelizing.

Unless your JVM has access to a ridiculously large number of physical cores, breaking up the computation into 5<sup>12</sup> potentially parallel tasks / steps is a bad idea.